# Can we generate odoo reports in excel format?

Tags: odoo, reporting, odoo-8

Currently i'm generating OpenErp reports as PDF format from RML code using "OpenErp report Designer" in openoffice .

But  how can I generate the report in xls format instead of PDF using same RML code.

If any one have solution / answer please Let me know .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Best way to generate Simple xls Report is to use xls_report Module which has xls report engine.

But for complex Designer xls Reports, use xlwt package of python.